# How to show employees details on ListView from ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Here I am taking three ArrayList (EmpName, EmpID and EmpPhone).
 In this, I am storing 5 data in each arraylist and after that I'm trying to show 
all data on listview like in each row of list view there will be 3 data.but I'm not 
getting exact output. Here my entire code...Please help... Thank you.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
```

**custom_checkbox.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_empname_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_empid_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_empphone_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ArrayList<String> EmpName;
    ArrayList<String> EmpID;
    ArrayList<String> EmpMobile;

    void getEmpDetails() {

        EmpName.add("Jhon");
        EmpName.add("Joy");
        EmpName.add("Jain");
        EmpName.add("Jason");
        EmpName.add("Joky");

        EmpID.add("1001");
        EmpID.add("1002");
        EmpID.add("1003");
        EmpID.add("1004");
        EmpID.add("1005");

        EmpMobile.add("8179789878");
        EmpMobile.add("8179789478");
        EmpMobile.add("8179789378");
        EmpMobile.add("8179789278");
        EmpMobile.add("8179789678");        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_listView1);



    }

    class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return EmpName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int index, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_checkbox, null);

            TextView t1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custom_empname_textView);
            TextView t2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custom_empid_textView);
            TextView t3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custom_empphone_textView);

            EmpName = new ArrayList<String>();
            EmpID = new ArrayList<String>();
            EmpMobile = new ArrayList<String>();

            getEmpDetails();

            ArrayAdapter<String> a1 = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, EmpName);

            ArrayAdapter<String> a2 = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, EmpID);

            ArrayAdapter<String> a3 = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, EmpMobile);

            t1.setText((CharSequence) a1);
            t2.setText((CharSequence) a2);
            t3.setText((CharSequence) a3);

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your questions and issues, I would suggest you below points:

1. **Manage a single ArrayList:**
   Managing different ArrayLists for the same object would be hard to manage. Like you are managing 3 ArrayList for storing information of Employee. Instead, you should manage a single ArrayList where Employee is a class.
2. **Get particular Employee object:** You can get particular Employee object inside the `getView()` method by `position`.
3. You are creating ArrayAdapter inside getView() method of your custom adapter. Not required at all.

And your code requires so many changes, better you get any android book and learn Android programming well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work, because you are using adapter wrong (and not setting to ListView at all).
Unfortunately, your code needs too many changes (for example, you should change new object Employee, you should pass array of these objects to adapter and bing values of Employee to item views) for resolving it in my answer, so just read good tutorial about adapters and try to write this code again:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Hope it helps.